# How to set maximum video width in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I set the maximum dimensions of a video in ffmpeg?
I want my videos to be 600:-1 or smaller. If I use `-vf scale=600:-1`, then it'd work with videos bigger than 600:-1 but the smaller videos would get bigger!
What's the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [expression](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation):

```
-vf "scale='min(600,iw)':-1"
```

If you need the auto-calculated height to be divisible by 2 then change `-1` to `-2`.