# How to read the following ffmpeg instruction?

Tags: ffmpeg

l'm newbie at video processing .

1. I would like to understand how to read the following **ffmpeg** instruction below

   ```
   import subprocess
   L=subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i %s -r 1 -s qvga -t 1 -f image2 %s' % (videoName,frameName), shell=True)
   ```
2. Through this instruction , how can l adapt it to get all the frames of a given video ?

Thank you

Comment: First, read `man ffmpeg`, which list all the `ffmpeg` functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### I would like to understand how to read the following ffmpeg instruction

Your `ffmpeg` command is semi-obfuscated by scripting so the actual command is not known, but here's an explanation of each option:

- `-i` indicates the input.
- `-r 1` sets output frame rate to 1. This is not needed if you want to output a single image or if you want to output all images. In this example it is used to output one frame per second which would skip many frames.
- `-s qvga` sets output width x height to "qvga" which is an alias for 320x240.
- `-t 1` sets the output duration to 1 second. This is not needed if you want to output a single image or if you want to output all images. It is often added by rookie users trying to output a single image but `-frames:v 1` should be used instead.
- `-f image2` An often superfluous option used to set the output format or muxer. It is used if your output name is ambiguous (perhaps due to scripting). Otherwise, `ffmpeg` will automatically choose the proper muxer for image outputs.

> #### how can l adapt it to get all the frames of a given video ?

The simplest, unscripted command to get all of the frames is:

```
ffmpeg -i input %04d.png
```

This will output `0001.png`, `0002.png`, `0003.png`, etc. If you want more than a numerical sequence you can use something like `output_%05d.png` which would result in `output_00001.png`.

For more info see [FFmpeg Documentation: Image Muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2).

Comment: Thanks a lot @LordNeckbeard. What about an alea of 224x224 ?

Comment: @Joseph There are several methods: `ffmpeg -i input -s 224x224 %04d.png` or to preserve aspect `ffmpeg -i input -vf scale=224:-1 %04d.png` or to prevent it from upscaling see [How to set maximum video width in ffmpeg?](https://askubuntu.com/a/772612/59378), or to fit it in a 244x244 box see [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit into static sized player](https://superuser.com/a/1136305/110524).

Comment: THANK YOU.  Since we extract all the frames of a video. Is it supposed by default that 24 fps (frame per second) ? or it's up to ffmpeg to adapt the scale acording to the speed of video, it can more / less than 24fps ?

Comment: @Joseph Input frame rate doesn't matter. As a gross simplification, if there are 500 frames in the video it will output ~500 frames.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
L=subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i %s -r 1 -s qvga -t 1 -f image2 %s' % (videoName,frameName), shell=True)
```

Information:

1. `import subprocess`: The subprocess module enables you to start new applications from your Python program.
2. `L=subprocess.call(...)`: Assign the output of the `call()` method to variable `L`.
3. `ffmpeg -i %s -r 1 -s qvga -t 1 -f image2 %s' % (videoName,frameName), shell=True`: Command to run  here `ffmpeg`
4. `-i %s`: input file name **gotten** from `videoName` variable --> `input file url`
5. `-r 1`: frame rate.
6. `-s qvga`: frame size.
7. `-f image2`: Force input or output file format
8. `-t 1`: When used as an output option (before an output url), stop writing the output after its duration reaches
          duration.
9. `% (videoName,frameName)`: Python string formatting that will replace `%s` sequences in the previous string with the items in the tuple.
10. `shell=True`: Make use of specific shell features like word splitting or parameter expansion

Usage:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess 
L=subprocess.call('ffmpeg -r 5 -i out.ogv fmprg_%04d.png', shell=True)
L()
```

- Make executable: `chmod u+x filename.sh`,
- Run with: `./filename.sh`

Information:

`fmprg_%04d.png`: Creates images with `0000, 0001, 0002, 0004, ...` between `fmprg_` and `.png`.

Read:

`man ffmpeg`

https://pythonspot.com/en/tag/subprocess/